# Trying to install openssl 1.1.0 fails make test

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to install `openssl 1.1.0`.

I've run `./config && make && make test`

And I fail [this test](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/test/recipes/40-test_rehash.t):

```
../test/recipes/40-test_rehash.t ........... 1/5
#   Failed test 'Testing that we aren't running as a privileged user, such as root'
#   at ../test/recipes/40-test_rehash.t line 49.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 5.
../test/recipes/40-test_rehash.t ........... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100) Failed 1/5 subtests
        (less 1 skipped subtest: 3 okay)
```

I don't think I can install this without being root. 
What am I missing ?

Comment: Running the test suite and installing are two different things. Do the former as non-root and the latter was root or use sudo.

Comment: I've trying su to another user, but the doesn't doesn't run at all now. /bin/sh: line 0: cd: test: Not a directory
Can't open perl script ".././test/run_tests.pl": No such file or directory

Comment: Try to `config`, `make` and `make test` as non-superuser and then only do su/sudo for the `make install` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip tests: `./config && make && make install`

But the best way: **try to find proper package for you distro**.

Comment: +1 for advising for using the package shipped with the distribution. But I would not call "skipping tests" a good advise, without explaining why.

Comment: @Daniel I suggested to skip the tests only to show that it is technically possible. This is not a recommendation.

Answer (score 6):

Did you read the `README` file?
Under the part "Installation in Detail" in step Nr.3:

> 3. After a successful build, the libraries should be tested. Run:'......

there is a note written

> NOTE: **you MUST run the tests from an unprivileged account** (or disable your privileges temporarily if your platform allows it).

So maybe you should run

```
make  
make test  
sudo make install
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I just finished building OpenSSL 1.1.0f on Solaris 10. These are the steps I had to take to get it to build and test successfully. I verified these as the minimum steps for the version of Solaris I'm running. I have also discovered everything before doing "make install" should be run as a non-privileged user.

**Update to newer version of Perl (Solaris default is 5.8.4, too old)**

```
 # /opt/csw/bin/pkgutil -y -i CSWperl
 # mv /usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/perl_5.8.4
 # ln -s /opt/csw/bin/perl /usr/bin/perl
```

**Install Perl modules:**

```
 # cpan
 cpan> install LWP
 cpan> install YAML
 cpan> upgrade
 cpan> exit
 # cpan
 cpan> install Test::More
 cpan> install Text::Template
 cpan> exit
```

**Add "-xarch=sparc" to the 00-base-templates.conf**

```
# vi openssl-1.1.0f/Configurations/00-base-templates.conf
```

**Set Libraries path**

```
 # LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql
```

**Configure**

```
 # ./config --prefix=/usr/openssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl
```

**Run the make stuff**

```
 # make depend
 # make
 # make test
[ ... ]
All tests successful.
Files=95, Tests=493, 831 wallclock secs ( 2.27 usr  1.56 sys + 697.89 cusr 57.54 csys = 759.26 CPU)
Result: PASS

`test' is up to date.
```